# hibernate working in an unplugged laptop

Tags: laptop

I have a laptop without a battery, **sometimes** when I close the lid of my laptop(hibernate) and there is a energy cut, and then is reestablished, I still have the session open.

Where the energy necesary to mantain that low-power state ,that is hibernate, is stored? if I dont have a battery?

why happens sometimes,not all the times?

Comment: AFAIK hibernation is done by storing the whole memory state image onto a hard disk, and then just loaded from there instead of initiating the whole startup procedure. So the state is retained across the power cycles.

Comment: Thanks I didnt know that. but sometimes when this happens I open the lid and all my running apps are there ready to use, and another times I have to power up the laptop again, to my understanding hibernate needs energy to survive, so where is stored if I dont have a battery?

Comment: Your understanding is not correct.  If you hibernate a Windows session, your current sessions is stored on the HDD, and the PC is turned off.  If you put your PC to sleep that requires a battery. "During a full shutdown and boot (S5), the entire user session is torn down and restarted on the next boot. In contrast, during a hibernation (S4), the user session is closed and the user state is saved."

Comment: You don't need a battery for hibernation, but you do need a battery to complete the hibernation saving. if you close the lid, and it goes into hibernation, and you cut the power too quickly, it can't complete and thus you lose the state.

Comment: Also, by default your laptop will NOT go into hibernation when you close the lid, but it will turn off the screen. Powersettings tell that if the laptop is in this state for 30 minutes, it will then hibernate.

Comment: Also one last note: You mention, but doesn't hibernation require some form of power? No, but suspension does. Suspension is a form of sleep that freezes the content of ram and forces the computer to turn off everything but only keep power to the memory active, so it is in a very low power setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## What happens when you close the lid of a laptop?

The screen will be turned off, ready to resume when you open the lid, and so that there is little energy wasted on the battery.

## When does my laptop go into hibernation?

This is a setting defined in your PowerManagement options. The powerscheme has a setting that says what to do if the computer is not attended for x minutes. By default, the scheme is set to balanced, and the default settings are: After 15 minutes, turn off the screen, after 30 minutes, put the laptop to hibernation.

## What is hibernation and how does it work?

Hibernation saves the content of your memory entirely to the harddisk. It then shuts down the laptop and completely turns it off. At this point the laptop does not consume any power anymore. Starting up the laptop, it will know there is an active session stored on the harddrive and it will resume that session.

## How come sometimes I get my session, and other times not?

If your laptop does not succesfully goes into hibernation and you cut the power, it will not be able to resume the session, and thus you lose the state of the running programs. If you wait more than 30 minutes it will suspend and turn off and you can safely cut the power.

## Is there a way to tell which state the laptop is in?

Yes, a laptop that is not in standby should display more lights, where a laptop in hibernation should not show any lights at all.

## How can I make it so that my laptop always goes into hibernation?

The easiest way is to go to your PowerManagement options and find the setting: Choose what to do when I close the lid. Change it to: Put the laptop into hibernation.

Be sure that after you set this setting, that it can take upto a minute before the laptop is fully hibernated. You will know because the laptop is fully powered down. No lights, no fan, all is off. Only then, you know that it is safe to unplug the power.